# I accidentally clicked the 'unlink data block' button under texture slots and it deleted all my progress

Tags: texture-painting

I accidentally clicked a X button called 'unlink data blocks' while wrapping up my texture painting. I had thought it would just temporarily take off the texture until I link it back again. Turns out it deletes your texture from existence unless you had pressed a shield button or exported the image file. Why this button exists I'm not sure. Is there any way to get my edited texture file back?

Comment: "Why this button exists I'm not sure." Seems quite logical to have the option to delete things in your file if you no longer need them, don't you think? :D Blender really cant tell, what you need and don't unless you tell it by clicking stuff :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it saved it but blender makes automatic backups.
Next to your file there should be .blend1 file, this is a backup and you can rename it to .blend.

Blender also saves autosaves into a directory.
You open it through File -> Recover -> Auto Save...
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked my autosaves but the texture I worked on did not show up. I've concluded it's gone forever. I know now how dangerous this button is and not to click it again. It would have been nice if it had prompted me with a 'are you sure'.

Comment: Please note that painted image textures will not be saved with the blend file if they are not packed. By default they are not packed but saved externally.

Comment: Yea you're right. Blender often lets you do dangerous stuff without warnings. Except when deleting the default cube of course (: